# What does it mean for a Vector field to be tangent at every point of S?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, surface-integrals

As background, I am in Vector Calculus. My question is giving me some "short cuts" to use to help with evaluating flux integrals. The hint says "If F (Vector Field) is tangent at every pointof S, then the integral of S of F dot dA =0. What does this mean exactly? How can I know if this vector field is tangent?

The second hint is "If F is perpendicular at every point of S and has a constant magnitude on S, then the integral of S of F dot dA = +/- ||F|| dot Area of the Surface (choose the positive sign if F points in the same direction s the orientation of S, Choose negative if F points in the direction opposite the orientation of S)

I am having trouble understand what these hints mean and when/ how to use them.

The Flux integral I have to solve is: F=e^(y^2+z^2)i through the disk of radius 2 in the yz-plane, centered at the origin and oriented in the positive x direction

Comment: What is it you find confusing? The concept of a vector field? The concepts of being "tangent" or "perpendicular" to a surface at a point? The concept of "magnitude" of a vector? The dot product? The concept of the normal to a surface? If you understand all of those, then this is straight-forward, so obviously you are weak on some of them, but which?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you learned in your class about the normal vector to a surface at a point. Saying the vector field is "*tangent to the surface*" means that the vector field is perpendicular to the normal vector of the surface. Geometrically/visually, this means the vector points in a direction within the tangent plane at that point.

So if $F$ is the vector field, and $dA$ is the normal to the surface, then $F \cdot dA = 0$, because they are perpendicular. If you integrate zero, you get zero.

The second hint is similar. Saying the vector field is "*perpendicular to the surface*" means that it points in the same (or opposite) direction of the normal vector everywhere. I guess the notation you are using probably means $dA$ is the *unit* normal vector. Then $F \cdot dA = \pm |F|$. Remember that if two vectors $v$ and $w$ are parallel, then $|v \cdot w| = |v| |w|$.

So if $|F|$ is the same length everywhere, then $F \cdot dA = \pm |F|$ is a *constant* function on the surface (it's the same at every point). Integrating a constant function is that constant times the area (this is just a basic principle about double integrals).